# How can I access an object of a nested dictionary by the value of an inner key (in JS)?

Tags: javascript, json, dictionary

I try to get one object by the value of an inner key of a nested dictionary in JS:

Example dictionary (in console.log):

```
{0: Object { fid: 4, ...}
1: Object {fid:5, ...}
...}
```

I can return the object keys `Object.keys(object)` in the console.log():

```
 ["0","1",...]
```

The following function then returns value undefined:

```
function get_fid(object, value) {
       console.log(object);
       console.log(value);
       return Object.keys(object).find(key => object[key]["fid"] === value);
    }
```

I know how to access the dictionary in python but I need to find the object with JS.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Just note that there is no such thing as a dictionary in JS. We must assume you mean "object". - May you also share how you are using `get_fid`?

Comment: Try using `==` instead of `===`.

Comment: What is `value`?  Could you be comparing strings and integers?

Comment: Usually keys `0`, `1`, `2`, ... are an array. Why is this an object?

Comment: Thank you @Barmar it worked with using `==` instead of `===`

Answer (score 0):

## Cannot reproduce

Check again the data passed to the parameters, as it worked perfectly here.

```js
const obj= {0:{fid: 4}, 1: {fid:5}}

function test(object, value) {
    return Object.keys(object).find(key => object[key]["fid"] === value);
}

const result = test(obj, 5) // return 1
document.getElementById('ex').innerHTML = result
```

```html
<h1 id="ex"></h1>
```

Comment: If you believe that the code has no issue, then please flag the question "cannot reproduce"

Comment: Also please may you not call an object "jsonExample" when it's not JSON?

Comment: sorry, it is the custom to work with json, but it is possible to understand.

Comment: It’s not json though? Remember JSON is a string and must first be parsed.

Comment: the structure is similar, almost identical to a json string as you say, for me a json is represented by {key: value}, of course a json file is represented in string and an object in javascript already has the difference that double quotes, so I don't see the need to put a huge difference in them.

Comment: i'm sleepy and i'm using google translator to send these messages, so there may be some typos, forgive me.

Comment: Don't worry. I'm just trying to make sure that we understand the differences between a JS object and JSON. The difference is more than the double-quotes, but I shall leave it at that

Comment: I understand that you don’t mean it, I’m also sorry for writing poorly written text. I'm going to sleep, bye.

Answer (score 0):

Can you show how did you get the `object` variable?

I could not replicate the issue and have created a snippet here for you to test out

Also if you want to have the object instead of the key, you may want to use

```
Object.values(obj).find(v=> v.fab === valueToFind)
```

```js
obj = {
    0: {fid: 4},
    1: {fid: 5},
}

const get_fid = (object, value) =>  Object.keys(object).find(key => object[key]["fid"] === value)

console.log(get_fid(obj, 4))

document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = get_fid(obj, 5)
```

```html
<div id="result" />
```

Answer (score 0):

It worked by using `==` instead of `===` in the function:

```
function get_fid(object, value) {
       console.log(object);
       console.log(value);
       return Object.keys(object).find(key => object[key]["fid"] == value);
    }
```